# How do I get the area of a GeoJSON polygon with Python

Tags: python, geojson, pyproj

I have the GeoJSON

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [[13.65374516425911, 52.38533382814119], [13.65239769133293, 52.38675829106993], [13.64970274383571, 52.38675829106993], [13.64835527090953, 52.38533382814119], [13.64970274383571, 52.38390931824483], [13.65239769133293, 52.38390931824483], [13.65374516425911, 52.38533382814119]]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

which http://geojson.io displays as

[image]

I would like to calculate its area (87106.33m^2) with Python. How do I do that?

### What I tried

```
# core modules
from functools import partial

# 3rd pary modules
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
from shapely.ops import transform
import pyproj

l = [[13.65374516425911, 52.38533382814119, 0.0], [13.65239769133293, 52.38675829106993, 0.0], [13.64970274383571, 52.38675829106993, 0.0], [13.64835527090953, 52.38533382814119, 0.0], [13.64970274383571, 52.38390931824483, 0.0], [13.65239769133293, 52.38390931824483, 0.0], [13.65374516425911, 52.38533382814119, 0.0]]
polygon = Polygon(l)

print(polygon.area)
proj = partial(pyproj.transform, pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:4326'),
                   pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:3857'))
print(transform(proj, polygon).area)
```

It gives `1.1516745933889345e-05` and `233827.03300877335` - that the first one doesn't make any sense was expected, but how do I fix the second one? (I have no idea how to set the `pyproj.Proj` init parameter)

I guess `epsg:4326` makes sense at it is WGS84 ([source](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/wgs-84/)), but for [epsg:3857](http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/6864/) I'm uncertain.

### Better results

The following is a lot closer:

```
# core modules
from functools import partial

# 3rd pary modules
import pyproj
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
import shapely.ops as ops

l = [[13.65374516425911, 52.38533382814119, 0],
     [13.65239769133293, 52.38675829106993, 0],
     [13.64970274383571, 52.38675829106993, 0],
     [13.64835527090953, 52.38533382814119, 0],
     [13.64970274383571, 52.38390931824483, 0],
     [13.65239769133293, 52.38390931824483, 0],
     [13.65374516425911, 52.38533382814119, 0]]
polygon = Polygon(l)

print(polygon.area)
geom_area = ops.transform(
    partial(
        pyproj.transform,
        pyproj.Proj(init='EPSG:4326'),
        pyproj.Proj(
            proj='aea',
            lat1=polygon.bounds[1],
            lat2=polygon.bounds[3])),
    polygon)
print(geom_area.area)
```

it gives 87254.7m^2 - that is still 148m^2 different from what geojson.io says. Why is that the case?

Comment: Because Web Mercator doesn't preserve area: http://www.geography.hunter.cuny.edu/~jochen/GTECH361/lectures/lecture04/concepts/Map%20coordinate%20systems/Map%20projections%20and%20distortion.htm. Welcome to map projections. Your question is a better for [GIS.SE] (There's nothing wrong with your *code*, just your choice of projection.) and is better off being specific about getting the wrong value for the area. And [here](https://epsg.io/3857)'s a link to the actual 3857 projection; the one you link is something else.

Comment: For anyone trying our the attached python code and getting an error, it should be `lat_1` and `lat_2` instead of `lat1` and `lat2`

Answer (score 9):

It looks like geojson.io is not calculating the area after projecting the spherical coordinates onto a plane like you are, but rather using a specific algorithm for calculating the area of a polygon on the surface of a sphere, directly from the WGS84 coordinates. If you want to recreate it you can find the source code [here](https://github.com/mapbox/geojson-area/blob/master/index.js).

If you are happy to carry on projecting the coordinates to a flat system to calculate the area, since it's good enough accuracy for your use case, then you might trying using [this](https://epsg.io/5243) projection for Germany instead. E.g:

```
from osgeo import ogr
from osgeo import osr

source = osr.SpatialReference()
source.ImportFromEPSG(4326)

target = osr.SpatialReference()
target.ImportFromEPSG(5243)

transform = osr.CoordinateTransformation(source, target)

poly = ogr.CreateGeometryFromJson(str(geoJSON['features'][0]['geometry']))
poly.Transform(transform)
poly.GetArea()
```

which returns `87127.2534625642`

Comment: Hmm... Is there a simple answer what the correct projection is? What are the main differences between 4326 and 5243?

Comment: @MartinThoma There is no such thing as a simple answer to "the correct projection." All the projections have different properties. It very much depends on your specific use case. In particular, a lot of projections give accurate values only in certain areas of the world.

Comment: This is super interesting! Could you name two reasonable projections for Berlin and their advantages compared to each other?

Answer (score 4):

There is a port of Mapbox's geojson-area for Python: https://pypi.org/project/area/

```py
from area import area

geoJSON = json.loads(...)

print(area(geoJSON['features'][0]['geometry']))
```

With your GeoJSON, it returns `87106.33` like on http://geojson.io/.